# fetch image by using url

Tags: objective-c

I want image on view by fetching it from some url. I want changing in given code..

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated{
        [super viewWillAppear:animated];
        UIImage *image = [[UIImage imageNamed:<#(NSString *)name#>
        NSString * mediaUrl = [[[self appDelegate]currentlySelectedBlogItem]mediaUrl];
        [[self image]setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"unknown.jpg"]];
        if(nil != mediaUrl){
            NSData* imageData;
            [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = YES;
            @try {
                imageData = [[NSData alloc]initWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString:mediaUrl]];
            }
            @catch (NSException * e) {
                //Some error while downloading data
            }
            @finally {
                UIImage * imageFromImageData = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];
                [[self image]setImage:imageFromImageData];
                [imageData release];
                [imageFromImageData release];
            }
            [UIApplication sharedApplication].networkActivityIndicatorVisible = NO;
        }
        self.titleTextView.text = [[[self appDelegate] currentlySelectedBlogItem]title];
        self.descriptionTextView.text = [[[self appDelegate] currentlySelectedBlogItem]description]; 
    }
```

Comment: @user766063 Hi, and welcome on stackoverflow. You can format your source code by selecting the code and click on the {} button. What is the problem with the given code?

Comment: The problem with the code above is that it blocks your UI so the image request definitely shouldn't be in viewWillAppear method. I'd start selector in background and then notify the main thread when image is downloaded.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the following:

```
         NSString *url=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Your URL"];
        //NSLog(@"URL=%@",url);
        UIImage *myImage=[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData UIImage *myImage=[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:[NSURL URLWithString: url]]];
        NSLog(@"%d byte of data", [[NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: [NSURL URLWithString: url]] length]); 

        if (myImage)
        {
         //THIS CODE WILL STORE IMAGE DOCUMENT DIRECTORY
            NSString *jpegFilePath = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/%@.jpg",[self pathForDocumentDirectory],[self.idOfImagesToDownload objectAtIndex:i]];
            NSData *data1 = [NSData dataWithData:UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myImage, 1.0f)];//1.0f = 100% quality
            [data1 writeToFile:jpegFilePath atomically:YES];
        }
```

NOTE:[self pathForDocumentDirectory] is method returning path of document directory.

Answer (score 0):

Using this will give you a solution

```
NSURL    *url  = [NSURL URLWithString:@"ENTER YOUR URL HAVING THE IMAGE"];
NSData   *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
```